# Form.ShowDialog in hidden application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application which runs in hidden mode. In new version I need to update database that is why I need to show some form to get some data from user for update. I use `Form.ShowDialog` method but errors occurred. It is said in error that

> "Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not
>   running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the
>   ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a
>   notification from a service application".

I guess that I need to show form in other way but I don't know how.

It works fine when i run this, i guess i should call it server, manually. But when another service starts it 
code:

```
  System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(path);
  startInfo.WorkingDirectory = ServerModel.ServerInfo.ServerDir;
  startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
```

This error occurs.

Comment: Your code is calling or attempting to show a dialog from somewhere (middle tier, server, web service, windows service etc) where it cannot display that dialog or probably doesn't know what Windows Forms are for that matter.

Comment: I edit my question to clarify.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "hidden mode"?

Comment: If you cannot show a dialog, why would you be able to show any UI?

Comment: I mean startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says you have to set the options of `MessageBox.Show` to either `ServiceNotification` or `DefaultDesktopOnly`. This applies to a MessageBox you probably try to show in your application.

Comment: I try to display not a messagebox but my defined winform.

Comment: But I guess you are trying to show a MessageBox inside there. That is the error you get. But probably, as the other answer said, you want to rethink your application design.

Comment: Any luck in find a solution?

Comment: Actually i think the problem was in other thing. The special service start this server and that mean that windows don't know whom it should show ui.Actually when i delete startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; line, even the descriptor of main window hadn't been create.That is why we remake the procedure of update.

Comment: Okay, but it is possible to post messages or windows to the default desktop by using one of the options I described above. The service needs to have the `Allow service to interact with desktop` option checked.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use windows balloon notifications, as they are mean't for showing messages from hidden apps.

See [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8fcf9a22-4749-4f71-8444-c46def69202f/how-to-display-a-notification-balloon-in-task-bar-with-a-meesage-from-a-a-winforms-application?forum=winforms) for reference.

Comment: If `ShowDialog()` fails, so will balloon notifications

Comment: By "hidden" you mean "minimized to tray". OP's "hidden" app is running as a Windows Service app.